# Unable to send a mail with an img tag in html using python sendgrid client

Tags: python, html, email, sendgrid

I'm receiving an html from the client side containing an img tag, for example:

```
<body>
<b>hello</b>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/KRnZgXh.jpg">
</body>
```

I'm trying to send this html using sendgrid.

I'm using python sendgrid client:

```
import sendgrid

sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('user@example.com', 'passwd')    
message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.add_to('Sample User<user@example.com>')
message.set_subject(subject)
message.set_html(content)            
message.set_from('Sample User<user@example.com>')
sg.send(message)
```

This doesn't succeed - the mail is not sent.

I'm able to send the same content using other mail services (mailgun for example).

Comment: `sg.send` gives you any error ? What it return value of `sg.send`?

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but your HTML is malformed - it should be `<img src="whatever" />` (note the closing) - it could be that sendgrid is parsing the document somehow and the `img` isn't parsed - but it'd help if you provided any errors returned

Comment: Hi, no error provided, i'm guessing it is blocked somewhere. I tried <img..../> didn't help

Comment: Can you send non-HTML emails via sendgrid? Rather than `message.set_html(content)` try `message.set_text('hello')`. If that works then it is probable that you are looking at an HTML issue. You might try including `<html>` opening and closing tags too.

Comment: Also, you might try using simple email addresses, i.e. `user@example.com` rather than `Sample User<user@example.com>`

Comment: Hi, I tested your code and it works. http://pastebin.com/WcNHezTv Not sure what you're encountering. Could you please print out the response from sg.send ?

Comment: I'm getting a 200 code as if the mail was sent. did you try sending an html with an img tag and an src inside?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to head over to [SendGrid's Code Workshop Tool](https://sendgrid.com/codeworkshop#/builder/library)

You can select the Python library, modify the data on the left, see the change in code on the right, and export it on the final step.

You can use this as a working example, or simply to compare it to the code you have going.